# Trying to remove a decimal from NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

This is bizarre.

Developing for the iPhone I have an NSString:

```
 distanceFromTargetString = @"6178266.000000"
 // this is not actually code, but a value taken from elsewhere. It is a proper NSString though.
```

When I use this

```
NSArray *listItems = [distanceFromTargetString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
distanceFromTargetString = [listItems objectAtIndex:0];
```

or this

```
 [distanceFromTarget setText: distanceFromTargetString];
```

I get something like this

```
-[NSDecimalNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cac40
2011-07-21 14:29:24.226 AssassinBeta[7230:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cac40'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try `[distanceFromTargetString integerValue]` ?

Comment: Thanks Vince. What does that do?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but this method doesn't work. Try posting it as answer anyway though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

```
NSInteger i = [distanceFromTargetString integerValue];
NSString s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
// you got your string
```

Answer (score 2):

At some point you are assigning an `NSDecimalNumber` to `distanceFromTargetString` rather than an `NSString`. There is no run-time type checking of assignments in Objective C, so this is totally "legal":

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber ....];
[array addObject:number];
NSString *string = [array lastObject];
```

The above will generate no errors or warnings until you try to send `NSString` methods to `string`, at which point you will get an exception (crash) like you show above.

Do an audit of everywhere you assign `distanceFromTargetString`, and everywhere you use `NSDecimalNumber`. Somewhere you're crossing the streams.

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhere calling `isEqualToString` with a `NSDecimalNumber` as the receiver. What is `distanceFromTarget`? Is this an `NSDecimalNumber`?

The first thing should work.

Comment: distanceFromTarget is a UILabel

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set a breakpoint at the line

```
[distanceFromTarget setText: distanceFromTargetString];
```

and see if distanceFromTargetString is actually an `NSString`.

As mentioned above, somehow an `NSNumber` has sneaked in somewhere.